# Does this waste memory with Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I am doing the following

```
int dimPx= (int)CommonFunc.convertDpToPixel(100, mCon);
imageView = new ImageView(mCon);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(dimPx,dimPx));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
Picasso.with(mCon).load(new File(filePathToImg).into(imageView);
```

Is this bad on the memory?  the only suspecion  I have is that I am using scaleType to be FITXY and  I am using Picasso to load the image there. Is it basically loading the whole image to memory or is Picasso smart enough to resize it to the imageview and store the sized one?

I tried to remove the FitXY and use Picasso.fit() but I didn't get the desired results. I want the image (loaded from local file on the device) to be sized down to fill the imageview "ignoring" the aspect ratio

Let me know if I am doing it the worng way and resulting in huge memory loss
Thanks

Comment: No answer on this?